# Unable to "cf push" into Bluemix, using swift_buildpack 2.0.5

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am no longer able to push my app to Bluemix. I am using the swift_buildback for a Kitura app.

The last time I successfully pushed it, was yesterday. I noticed that the default buildpack is now 2.0.5. The last time I pay attention to that, it was 2.0.4. I don't know how to specify an older version of the buildpack, to rule out a problem there.

The `cf push` returns the following:

```
Downloading swift_buildpack...
Downloaded swift_buildpack
Creating container
Successfully created container
Downloading app package...
Downloaded app package (46.5M)
Downloading build artifacts cache...
Downloaded build artifacts cache (43.9M)
Staging...
-----> Buildpack version 2.0.5
-----> Default supported Swift version is 3.1
-----> Configure for apt-get installs...
-----> Writing profile script...
-----> Copying deb files to installation folder...
-----> No Aptfile found.
-----> Getting swift-3.0.2
-----> WARNING: Default supported Swift version: swift-3.1
-----> WARNING: Requested Swift version for your app: swift-3.0.2
       Cached swift-3.0.2
-----> Unpacking swift-3.0.2.tar.gz
-----> Getting clang-3.8.0
       Cached clang-3.8.0
-----> Unpacking clang-3.8.0.tar.xz
-----> .ssh directory and config file not found.
-----> Loading from cache:
-----> - Packages
-----> Fetching Swift packages and parsing Package.swift files...
-----> Additional packages to download: libcurl4-openssl-dev openssl libssl-dev
-----> libcurl4-openssl-dev is already installed.
-----> openssl is already installed.
-----> libssl-dev is already installed.
-----> No additional packages to download.
-----> Skipping installation of App Management (debug)
-----> Installing system level dependencies...
-----> Installing deb_files
dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive `deb_files': No such file or directory
Failed to compile droplet
Exit status 223
Staging failed: Exited with status 223
Destroying container

FAILED
Error restarting application: BuildpackCompileFailed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to verify that your app works with the previous version of the buildpack, just add the `-b <buildpack name>` flag to your `cf push` command.

The names of the available buildpacks can be obtained by running `cf buildpacks`.  In this case, since you want the old 2.0.4 buildpack version, the command will look like this:
`cf push <app_name> -b swift_buildpack_v2_0_4-20170125-2344`

The team that administers the Swift buildpack for Bluemix can help troubleshoot issues like this in their open Slack team - https://swift-at-ibm-slack.mybluemix.net.

Comment: Thank you! I did find the `-b`, but didn't know how to get the buildpack name. With your help I can now confirm that the 2.0.4 buildpack works just fine. It is the new 2.0.5 that seems to be broken. I will use the link you provided to follow the matter there. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems 2.0.5 is just fine after all. As instructed by christian, I deleted the app (`cf delete <appname>` and then `cf push`. It works fine now. It seems there was a caching problem.

Comment: You have some control over the cache; it's on by default but `cf set-env myapp NODE_MODULES_CACHE false` will turn it off. Ref https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/configurationOptions.html#cache_behavior

Comment: Thanks. I came across that document in the past, but I could not find it again! Since I could not find the name of the variable, I knew that by modifying the Package.swift file, you also force the system to ignore the cache. However, that did not work either. Only deleting the app worked. Should it occur again, I will definetely try the NODE_MODULES_CACHE setting. Thanks!